# Проблемы с QAudioOutput

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Кроме шумов ничего нет. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    QByteArray array;

    QFile media;
    media.setFileName("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\song.mp3");
    media.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    array = media.readAll();
    media.close();

    QBuffer* buf = new QBuffer;
    buf->setBuffer(&array);
    buf->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    qDebug() << buf->size();

    QAudioFormat desiredFormat1;
    desiredFormat1.setChannelCount(2);
    desiredFormat1.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    desiredFormat1.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    desiredFormat1.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    desiredFormat1.setSampleRate(44100);
    desiredFormat1.setSampleSize(16);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info1(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if (!info1.isFormatSupported(desiredFormat1))
    {
        qWarning() << "Format not supported";
        desiredFormat1 = info1.preferredFormat();
    }

    QAudioOutput* audioOutpu = new QAudioOutput(desiredFormat1);
    audioOutpu->start(buf);

    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(audioOutpu, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    do {
        loop.exec();
    } while (audioOutpu->state() == QAudio::ActiveState);
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что ты mp3 файл пытаешься подсунуть как сырые (`"audio/pcm"`) данные...

Comment: И как это исправить?

Comment: смотря что ты хочешь... или передавать сырые данные, а не mp3, или декодировать файл...

Comment: Звучит не приятно...

Comment: да нет... просто определись, что нужно... для первого надо просто получить сырые данные, например с линейного входа из старенькой магнитолы с помощью `QAudioInput`, для второго просто вставить `QAudioDecoder` между файлом и `QAudioOutput` (подразумевая, что использование эксперементальных возможностей тебя устраивает и бекэнд `QAudioDecoder` поддерживает mp3).

Comment: А вам обязательно надо через QAudioOutput работать? Просто есть класс "повыше уровнем" QMediaPlayer

Comment: Я знаю про QMediaPlayer. Но мне он не подойдет под сервер. Я с сервера получаю массив байт QByteArray, в виде какой-нибудь песни, и мне ее нужно воспроизвести. Пытался я засунуть в QMediaPlayer QBuffer, но ничего не выходило путного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, нашел нужное решение для себя с использованием QMediaPlayer и QByteArray. Оно проще и легче.

```
QFile file("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\song.mp3");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray arr = file.readAll();
file.close();

QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;

QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(player);
buffer->setData(arr);
buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

player->setMedia(QMediaContent(), buffer);

player->play();
```